# KOMA-Script Chapter Headings

Tags: koma-script, sectioning

How can I change the default KOMA-Script chapter heading style to the default classes' style?

Specifically, how do I turn this:

[image: KOMA Style]

Into this:

[image: Default Style]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
```

run `texdoc scrbook` and you'll find it on page 42.

Comment: Well this is the right answer, I just can't mark it right now. I was unable to find that option in my documentation.

Comment: @Tiago: On our site it's recommended to [wait some time](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/209/1235) before accepting an answer, so there is no hurry. I'd say: wait at least 1 or 2 hours. (We actually even recommend waiting a day!)